# How to define the PropType shape if my react object contains either property a or b?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-proptypes

Consider I have an item object with the following properties. The first property key either be cpmd or cmd with the same shape. I am not sure how to validate this in PropType

```
item:{
     cpmd:{
          name: "ABC",
          details:{
                 images: some values
          }
     },
     onPress: function,
     index: number
}
```

Things that I have tried include

```
item: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropType.shape({
          cpmd: PropType.shape({//Other object PropTypes defined here}),
        PropType.shape({
          cmd: PropType.shape({//Other object PropTypes defined here})
      ]),
      //Other object PropTypes defined here
}
```

Somehow the above does not look correct. This is because when I want to use the cmd or cpmd in my component I have to destructure both as

```
const {cpmd,cmd}=item
```

Not really sure what would be the best way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define the type like this:

```
item : {
  cpmd: PropTypes.shape({//Other object PropTypes defined here}),
  cpm: PropTypes.shape({//Other object PropTypes defined here}),
};
```

Like this, cpmd and cpm are optional